# I can't award bounty to my own answer to my own question

Tags: support, bounties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

The title pretty much says it all...

[Loading compressed texture ETC1 in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12646796/loading-compressed-texture-etc1-in-android)

I think the bounty period ends today. I don't see any award bounty icon under the votes number in the answer.

Will the bounty be lost?

Answer (score 5):

Bounties are always lost, you're spending rep for publicity, not answers.

See [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) for a complete description of the ins and outs.